# Java Cryptography Extension

Tags: java, cryptography

I was told that in order to support AES256 encryption inside my Java app that I would need the JCE with Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files.

I downloaded this from Oracle and unzipped it and I'm only seeing 2 JARs:

- `local_policy.jar`; and
- `US_export_polic.jar`

I just want to confirm I'm not missing anything here! My understanding (after reading the `README.txt`) is that I just drop these two into my `<JAVA_HOME>/lib/security/` directory and they should be installed.

By the names of these JARs I have to assume that its not the Java Crypto API that cannot handle AES256, but it's in fact a **legal** issue, perhaps? And that these two JARs basically tell the JRE "*yes, it's legally-acceptable to run this level of crypto (AES256).*" Am I correct or off-base?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following blog post answers your questions:

http://blogs.adobe.com/livecycle/2011/10/configuring-the-jdk-for-rights-management-encryption-using-aes-256-bit-keys.html

You effectively need the two JARs to be able to use AES256 encryption, and you need to perform the following steps, and I quote:

> Copy the two JAR files to the your JDK’s /jre/lib/security/ folder, replacing the similarly named files that are already there.

Now, to the second part of your question: yes, it is dues to legal issues:

> Due to import control restrictions by the governments of a few
>   countries, the jurisdiction policy files shipped specify that “strong”
>   but limited cryptography may be used. An “unlimited strength” version
>   of these files indicating no restrictions on cryptographic strengths
>   is available for those living in eligible countries (which is most
>   countries). But only the “strong” version can be imported into those
>   countries whose governments mandate restrictions. The JCE framework
>   will enforce the restrictions specified in the installed jurisdiction
>   policy files.

Also, there is a related Q/A on the Security Stack: [Export laws on the cloud (key size)](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/5265). Although the question is specific to the cloud, the main answer covers more ground than just the "cloud" and lists the countries you cannot get a license to sell your software to and those for which your require an import permit.

Finally, you may find more information on Wikipedia about the [Export of cryptography in the United States](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Export_of_cryptography_in_the_United_States).

Comment: So it is a workaround for a law that really doesn't work... Interesting.

Comment: I'm still confused. Why does JRE come with lib/security/policy/unlimited and limited subfolders which seem to replicate these files? Thus, there are no files to replace in security folder, they are deeper. Can I delete the policy folder if I follow the readMe precisely? Size is an issue for us.